# Time Limit Exceeded while using concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, deadlock

This is a question from Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/print-zero-even-odd/

The output I'm getting for the below code is

```
01
```

Not sure why it's getting stuck at zero function. I'm changing the `state` to `ZERO` and notifying it to the thread, it's supposed to print 0 again, but it just stopped at 1

The expected output is `01020304050607.. and so on`

```
class ZeroEvenOdd {
      private int n;
    
      State state;
      Type prevState = Type.EVEN;
      int count = 1;
      public ZeroEvenOdd(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        state = new State(Type.ZERO);
      }
    
      // printNumber.accept(x) outputs "x", where x is an integer.
      public void zero(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(state) {
          while (state.type != Type.ZERO) {
            state.wait();
          }
    
          printNumber.accept(0);
          System.out.println(0);
          if (prevState == Type.EVEN)
            state.type = Type.ODD;
          else
            state.type = Type.EVEN;
    
          state.notifyAll();
    
        }
    
      }
    
      public void even(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        while (count < n) {
    
          synchronized(state) {
            while (state.type != Type.EVEN) {
              state.wait();
            }
            printNumber.accept(count);
            System.out.println(count);
    
            count++;
            prevState = state.type;
            state.type = Type.ZERO;
            state.notifyAll();
    
          }
        }
    
      }
    
      public void odd(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        while (count < n) {
          synchronized(state) {
            while (state.type != Type.ODD) {
              state.wait();
            }
    
            printNumber.accept(count);
            System.out.println(count);
    
            count++;
            prevState = state.type;
    
            state.type = Type.ZERO;
    
            state.notifyAll();
          }
        }
    
      }
    
      public class State {
    
        public Type type;
    
        public State(Type type) {
          this.type = type;
        }
      }
    
      public enum Type {
        ZERO,
        ODD,
        EVEN
      }
    
    }
```

Can anyone please help?
Thank you.

Comment: It’s not stuck at the `zero` method, the `zero` method finished. You didn’t do anything to make it print more than one zero.

Comment: @Holger I'm changing the state.type = Type.ZERO; and notifying it, the thread in zero function should come out of while loop then

Comment: Of course, it does. That’s why you see a zero in the output. And then, the method completes.

Comment: @Holger I might be conceptually wrong. I'm not sure how threads work exactly. I'm sorry, but I'm a newbie to this. I assumed that it'll come out, and it's not happening. I'm not sure why it's not happening.

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads. Your `zero` method contains a single `printNumber.accept(0);` statement and does nothing to execute it more than once. The other methods, `even` and `odd`, have their code within a `while (count < n)` loop but the `zero` method has no such thing.

Comment: @Holger oh, you're right! I feel dumb now!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find it out yourself through debugging.

Hint: the problem is in your `zero(..)` method.

Also, the fact that `while (count < n) {` is outside of `synchronized` blocks is a bug (data race(s)).